# getting height of the dynamically loaded div

Tags: jquery, ajax

i am facing some difficulty with getting the height of the dynamically loaded div image.. sometimes , it gives the correct height but sometimes it gives zero .. here is my code

```
$.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "images.php",
                        data: dataStr,
                        cache: false,
                        async : false,
                        success: function(data)
                        {

                        $('.up').empty();
                        $(".up").html(data);
                        alert($(".loadimg").height());

                          }
                         });
```

here is what i am appending

```
echo '<div class="imagediv">
    <img src="default.jpg"  class="loadimg" />
        </div>  ';
```

Comment: yes it is defined , its some data i am sending for ajax . everything works .. the only problem i am facing is that the image may not been loaded when i am calling the alert . i need to know how do i wait until the image is completely loaded .

Comment: you probably have to load the image with javascript

Comment: so you are saying there is no way we can find out when the ajax data is completely loaded ?

Comment: The image is loaded independently after the ajax and .html() calls. So you don't have onload event fired.. look here http://corpocrat.com/2009/07/02/how-to-check-if-image-loaded-or-not-in-javascript/. The other way is to check the width and height of the image but I personally don't like it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(".loadimg").load(function(){
                                alert($(".loadimg").height());
                            });`

Try this

```
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "images.php",
                    data: dataStr,
                    cache: false,
                    async : false,
                    success: function(data)
                    {
                        $('.up').empty();
                        $(".up").html(data);

                        $(".loadimg").load(function(){
                            alert($(".loadimg").height());
                        });
                      }
                     });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try .delegate() like this:

```
$(".up").delegate("img", "load", function() {
  alert($(".loadimg").height());
})

                $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax.php",
                async:false,
                success: function(data)
                  {
                    $('.up').empty();
                    $(".up").html(data);
                  }
                 });
```